# Nuspec dependencies necessary with PackageReferences

Tags: nuget, nuspec, packagereference

imagine the following situation:

Project A has some NuGet dependencies (ie Project Z, Project Y and Project X). It uses PackageReferences.

Now I want to pack Project A as a .nupkg using a .nuspec file. In a .nuspec file you can declare other NuGet dependencies and they will automatically resolved upon installation.

But is that necessary? I thought the PackageReferences would already resolve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `PackageReference` items in your project, you no longer need a `.nuspec` file to pack a project. You should be able to pack it with `dotnet pack -c Release` or `msbuild.exe -t:Pack -p:Configuration=Release`. (Depending on the project type, you may need to install the `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` for non-SDK-based .NET Framework projects. .NET Standard, Core, .NET 5+ projects should not need this)

You *can* still use a .nuspec file though, by specifying a `NuspecFile` property inside the csproj to instruct the pack task to use it. However, it will override all the settings that NuGet would autogenerate - that's the tradeoff for getting complete control over the `.nuspec`.

If you pack a project using `PackageReference` you can have a look at the generated `.nuspec` file in e.g. `obj\Release\FooLib.1.0.0.nuspec`.